# Set a different icon for imported projects in a SWT application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-mars

I have an Eclipse RCP application in which I can create custom projects (like the Java projects in Eclipse).

Now I have the case in which the users of the application can also import existing projects from another location (for example from the network) and they would like to differentiate between local and imported projects in their workspace by different icons.

The current project icon is set by setting a custom nature for the project. The nature is defined in the plugin.xml:

```
 <extension
   id="ProjectNature"
   name="Project Nature"
   point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
<runtime>
   <run
         class="myPackage.CustomProjectNature">
   </run>
</runtime>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.projectNatureImages">
  <image
  id="ProjectNature.image"
  natureId="myPackage.CustomProjectNature"
 icon="icons/projectIcon.gif">
</image>
</extension>
```

When creating a new project with the wizzard the nature is set:

```
final IProjectDescription description = p_projectHandle.getDescription();
final String[] natures = description.getNatureIds();
final String[] newNatures = new String[natures.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(natures, 0, newNatures, 0, natures.length);
newNatures[natures.length] = CustomProjectNature.NATURE_ID;
description.setNatureIds(newNatures);
p_projectHandle.setDescription(description, null);
```

When importing the same icon is set.

Is there any way to set a different icon for imported projects from another location?

Comment: How can we possibly answer this when you haven't told us anything about how you represent them in your app?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: So this is an Eclipse RCP not a plain SWT application?

Comment: Yes, it is an Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: How would any code in Eclipse know that the project was from somewhere else?